# dependent dropdown error 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django

```
   **PCR.html**


<div class="main-container">
            <p>PCR LIVE INDICATOR</p>
            <form method="POST" id="pcrchart" data-pcr-url="{% url 'ajax_expiry'%}">
                <div class="drop1">
                    <label>Select Symbol</label>

                    <select name="company" id="company" size="1">
                        <option value="" selected="selected">Nifty</option>
                        {%  for i in d %}
                        <option value="{{i.name}}">{{i.name}}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                </div>


                <div class="drop2">
                    <label>Select Expiry</label>
                    <select name="expiryDate" id="expiryDate" size="1">
                        
                    </select>

                </div>
                <div class="drop3">
                    <label>Select Strike</label>
                    <br>
                    <select name="price" id="price" size="1">
                        <option value="" selected="selected">12700</option>
                        {% for Price in Prices %}
                        <option value="{{price.pk}}">{{price.name}}</option>
                        {% endfor %}

                    </select>
                </div>

            </form>
```

**pcr1.html**

```
<option value="" selected="selected">27 Aug 2020</option>
{% for expiryDate in expiry %}
<option value="{{expiryDate.expiry}}" title="27 Aug 2020">{{expiryDate.expiry}}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

**views.py**

```
def pcr(request):
    d={}
    d = stock.objects.all()
    return render(request,'pcr.html',{"d":d})

def expiry(request):
    name1 = request.GET.get('company')
    print(name1)
    expiry=NFO.objects.all().filter(name=name1)   
    return (request,'pcr1.html',{
        'expiry': expiry,
    })
```

i am write to write a dependent dropdown list .the first dropdown value is selected based on that on second dropdown there is an error thAT 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/ajax/expiry/?company=NIFTY
Django Version:     3.0.7
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:

'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py in process_response, line 26
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version:     3.8.3
Python Path:

['/root/Documents/optionplus',
'/usr/lib/python38.zip',
'/usr/lib/python3.8',
'/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
'/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages',
'/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
'/usr/lib/python3.8/dist-packages']

Server time:    Sat, 29 Aug 2020 20:57:06 +0530

Comment: In the web page, it looks like you're using POST. Try using `name1 = request.POST.get('company')` in your code.

Comment: it still gives the same error . although the error is solved i used the JsonResponse